# Nomenclature of radial solutions to the Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, terminology

For the free particle with quantum number $l=0$, the ***regular*** solution to the radial Schrodinger equation is $R_0 (\rho)=\frac{\sin{\rho}}{\rho}$ while the ***irregular*** solution is $R_0 (\rho)=\frac{\cos{\rho}}{\rho}$. Is there a reason for this nomenclature -- (ir)regular? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this nomenclature is the behavior at $r=0$:

$$\lim_{r\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin r}{r} = 1,$$

$$\lim_{r\to0^{+}}\frac{\cos r}{r} = \infty .$$

$\frac{\sin r}{r}$ is **regular** at $r=0$ while $\frac{\cos r}{r}$ is **irregular**.

Comment: Thanks, luksen. You mean the regular solution doesn't blow up at $r=0$ while the irregular one does, right? I am not entirely sure why you are taking the limit $r\to\infty$, but I can see that $\lim_{\rho\to0} \frac{\sin{\rho}}{\rho} = 1$ while $\lim_{\rho\to0} \frac{\cos{\rho}}{\rho}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry.. of course the limit should go to 0. will edit

Comment: And the reason why this is regular is that the regular wavefunction is well behaved--satisfying $\int \psi^{*}\psi=$finite, which makes it normalizable and capable of representing the probability distribution of a particle's position.